# Emacs client broken when used as editor by other tool

Tags: terminal, emacs, tmux

I've had an issue for a while, and I cannot figure out how to fix it. Here is what happens:

When I use a tool that reads out the $EDITOR variable to let me edit something (e.g. `kubectl edit something`), it launches an `emacsclient` instance connecting with an existing daemon. The file opens up and is shown. When I press any button, though, I just see the escape codes printed at the top. Nothing seems to actually be sent to `emacsclient` or `emacs`, it just prints the input directly on screen.

For context, this is my setup:

I use `mlterm` with a `tmux` session. Both are set to `xterm-256color` terminal. This works just fine. My default shell is `xonsh`. I launch `emacsclient` normally by calling `emacsclient -t` which I have on an alias. `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` are both set to `emacsclient -t -a=''`.

I am honestly out of ideas. I can set `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` to `vim` and it works, but that's hardly optimal. Did anyone ever see this behavior, even in a different context? That might already help me out here.

UPDATE: It actually works with just `$EDITOR=emacs -nw`. So it's an issue with emacsclient, it seems.